# How to Invite facebook friends though my application?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try using [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkapi) this. In this tutorial i post my app link only my wall. But i want to share my app link to all my friends. Same like as a **XYZ invited to you to try ABCapp** only in notification bar. When click on it open google play store of my app page. I want to share my app app link to app facebook friends or selected facebook friend. How can i achieve this?

Comment: no, it's is not a game. @gavdotnet

Comment: can u please give me tutorial for this? @gavdotnet

Comment: I have some sample code, but it would only work for sending app requests for a game.

Comment: Please send me this sample code for game request. shekhjigar@gmail.com @gavdotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To invite friends through your app you can use App Invites. Before using this feature make sure to set up your Android Facebook SDK version to 4.0 or later.

- You can take a look at the overview in this link
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview
- For the implementation you probably need this
  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android

Comment: App invites is now deprecated.

Comment: Links are not valid

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

> If your app has a Canvas presence, you may also use the Requests Dialog on iOS and Android
>
> **If your app does not have a presence on Facebook Canvas:** You may use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android, or the Send Dialog on Web

I assume you don´t have a Canvas presence? In that case you should not use App Requests.

Comment: Okay. But in my phone install one App. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.callapp.contacts&hl=en In this app Invite friends like what i want? @luschn

Comment: you can´t use app invites for android apps, only for apps on canvas. use the message dialog on android.

Comment: Slight correction, you CAN use the Requests dialog for Android apps, as long as your app ALSO has a Canvas presence (under the same app ID).

Comment: @MingLi: yeah, that´s in my answer, it was just not that clear in the comment, sorry.

Comment: @MingLi: I also follow this link for request https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests. Here, I send request successfully but in my friend's phone click on this notification nothing happen. So how to can i send my app play store link with this request?

Comment: so does your app have a canvas implementation?

Comment: No. I cannot implement canvas. @luschn

Comment: then you should not use requests, as you can read in the facebook docs. you need to use the message dialog on android. that´s the proper way to invite friends to a non-canvas app.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is the list of all the friends of user on facebook to invite them. you can get ALL friends' list only if your app is in "GAME" category.

If not, then you can still get the friend list of user , but only some, not all. refer to terms `friends` and `invitable_friends` on facebook.

So, here are few things you can do (BUT NOT RECOMMENDED AT ALL)

- Change the category of your app to "GAMES" & you'll be able to get
  all friend's list & then you can use `WebDialog` & `WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder` to invite that friends
- give any link to canvas URL on facebook app setting. that link  will be used only when user clicks your notification from web. that link won't affect your app in any way.

Comment: can u please give me tutorial for this? @sam_0829